# Reassigning variables in python

Tags: python

I have the following code and variables, and I want to find what the variables `a`, `a1`, `a2`, `b`, `b1`, and `b2` refer to after the code has been executed.

```
def do_something(a, b):
    a.insert(0, "z")
    b = ["z"] + b

a = ["a", "b", "c"]
a1 = a
a2 = a[:]
b = ["a", "b", "c"]
b1 = b
b2 = b[:]

do_something(a, b)
```

My attempted solution is as follows:

```
a = ["z", "a", "b", "c"]
a1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
a2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = ["z" "a", "b", "c"]
b1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
b2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

But the actual solution is:

```
a = ["z", "a", "b", "c"]
a1 = ["z", "a", "b", "c"]
a2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = ["a", "b", "c"]
b1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
b2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Can anyone walk me through my mistake?

Comment: At what point do you find/print out the values of all the variables? Perhaps this has something to do with scope

Comment: I think by "my attempted solution" you mean "what I'm expecting" ... is that correct?  That might clear up some confusion.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) may help understand why this happened

Answer (score 9):

Ok, you can think of variables in Python as references. When you do:

```
a1 = a
```

Both `a1` and `a` are references to the same object, so if you modify the object pointed by `a` you will see the changes in `a1`, because - surprise - they are the same object (and the `list.insert` method mutates the list in place).

But when you do:

```
a2 = a[:]
```

Then `a2` is a new `list` instance, and when you modify `a` you are not modifying `a2`.

The result of the `+` operator for lists is a new list, so when you do:

```
b = ['z'] + b
```

You are assigning a new list to `b` instead of mutating `b` in-place like you would do with `b.insert('z')`. Now `b` points to a new object while `b1` still points to the old value of `b`.

But the scopes can be even trickier: you can see the enclosing scope from a function, but if you assign a variable inside the function, it will not change the variable with the same name in the enclosing (or global, or built-in) scope, it will create a variable with this name in the local scope. This is why b was not changed - well, not quite, parameter passing in Python is an assignment operation, so `b` is already a local variable when there is a parameter named `b` - but trying to mutate a variable defined in the enclosing scope leads to a similar problem. BTW, it is bad practice to rely on variables from the enclosing scope unless they are module-level constants (traditionally they are named in ALL_UPPERCASE style and you are not supposed to mutate them). If you need the value inside the function, pass it as a parameter, and it you want to change the value of the variable in the enclosing scope, return the value and assign the returned value there:

```
def do_something(a, b):
    a.insert(0, "z")  # mutates a in-place
    return ["z"] + b

b = do_something(a, b)
```

Comment: also worth mentioning `b` in `do_something` has been reassigned locally, so that doesn't change the global `b` value.

Comment: The value of `b` calculated in `do_something()` is local to the function and is thrown away when that function ends. None of the global variables `b`, `b1`, or `b2` are touched by the function.